# How come I don't see grub every time I boot?

Tags: grub2, monitor

I have noticed that when grub boots up I don't get a black screen on my monitor. I want to make it so that it will show every time I boot, not just when I turn it off manually and then turn it on again. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit /etc/default/grub and edit lines to look like:
`GRUB_DEFAULT=0

#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0

GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false

GRUB_TIMEOUT=10`
After you've done this run `sudo update-grub` and reboot. Now the grub menu should appear.